# how do i get the user information signed in with firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, next.js

i am trying to display a users name in the header of my prohect after signed in with fire base i read the docs . This is the code i got from the docs to handle user information . However , i keep getting this error

> TypeError: (0 , firebase_auth__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.getAuth) is not a function

how do i fix this please

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;
if (user !== null) {
  // The user object has basic properties such as display name, email, etc.
  const displayName = user.displayName;
  const email = user.email;
  const photoURL = user.photoURL;
  const emailVerified = user.emailVerified;

  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
  // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
  // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
  const uid = user.uid;
}
```

But i keep getting this error

```
TypeError: (0 , firebase_auth__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.getAuth) is not a function
```

How do i fix it please . i attached my header code below

```
import Image from "next/image";
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css'
import firebase from "../Firebase/Firebase";
// import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/client"

import { MenuIcon, SearchIcon, ShoppingCartIcon } from "@heroicons/react/outline";

import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";


function Header() {




    const SigninWithFirebase = () => {
        let google_provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(google_provider).then((re) => {
            console.log(re);
        })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
    }




    const auth = getAuth();
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    if (user !== null) {
        // The user object has basic properties such as display name, email, etc.
        const displayName = user.displayName;
        const email = user.email;
        const photoURL = user.photoURL;
        const emailVerified = user.emailVerified;

        // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
        // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
        // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
        const uid = user.uid;
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <div className="flex items-center bg-amazon_blue p-1 flex-grow py-2">
                {/* top nav */}
                <div className=" mt-2 flex items-center flex-grow sm:flex-grow-0">
                    <Image src="https://links.papareact.com/f90"
                        width={150}
                        height={40}
                        objectFit="contain"
                        className="cursor-pointer"

                    />
                </div>

                {/* bottom nav */}

                {/* Search bar */}
                <div className="hidden sm:flex items-center h-10  cursor-pointer flex-grow rounded-md bg-yellow-400 hover:bg-yellow-500">
                    <input className="p-2 h-full w-6 flex-grow flex-shrink rounded-l-md focus:outline-none px-4 " type="text" />
                    <SearchIcon className="h-12 p-4" />
                </div>
                {/* Rigth */}
                <div className="text-white flex items-center text-xs space-x-6 mx-6 whitespace-nowrap">
                    <div onClick={SigninWithFirebase} className="signIn cursor-pointer links">
                        <p>hello </p>
                        <p className="font-extrabold md:text-sm">Account & list</p>
                    </div>

                    <div className="cursor-pointer  links">
                        <p>Returns</p>
                        <p className="font-extrabold md:text-sm">Orders</p>

                    </div>
                    <div className="cursor-pointer  relative links flex items-center">
                        <span className="absolute top-0 right-0 md:right-10 h-4 w-4 bg-yellow-400 text-center rounded-full text-black font-bold"> 0</span>
                        <ShoppingCartIcon className="h-10" />
                        <p className="hidden md:inline font-extrabold md:text-sm mt-2">Basket</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div className="space-between flex items-center space-x-3 p-2 pl-6 bg-amazon_blue-light text-white text-sm ">

                <p className="link flex items-center">
                    <MenuIcon className="h-6 mr-1" />
                    All
                </p>

                <p className="link">Men</p>
                <p className="link">Women</p>
                <p className="link">Shoes</p>
                <p className="link ">Accessories </p>
                <p className="link hidden lg:inline-flex">Latest</p>
                <p className="link hidden lg:inline-flex">Latest</p>
                <p className="link hidden lg:inline-flex">Latest</p>




            </div>
        </div>


    )
}

export default Header
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "with-redux-toolkit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.5.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.4",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.2.0",
    "firebase": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "next": "latest",
    "next-auth": "^3.29.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-currency-formatter": "^1.1.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-firebaseui": "^6.0.0",
    "react-redux": "7.2.2",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.22"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "postcss": "^8.2.15",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.1.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your `package.json` or firebase version?

Comment: You are using syntax of both V8 and V9. You should try to use only 1 of them depending on which version you are using.

Comment: i have added my package.json